# running into error when running ionic cordova emulate ios

Tags: ios, json, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

When trying to test my project on the ios emulator from Xcode on my Mac, i get the following error in the CLI :

```
 "Error: tsconfig: Cannot read file '/Users/catalin/VetLab/platforms/ios/cordova/tsconfig.json': ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/catalin/VetLab/platforms/ios/cordova/tsconfig.json'."
```

Comment: do you get the error when running with `serve` ?

Comment: Thanks for replying, but i have solved the problem meanwhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everybody who has tried to help me with this problem. The solution I found was to run the command in the terminal after opening the IOS emulator in Xcode.